# Trouble getting PHP to run on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm rolling out a microsite on AWS that needs to use PHP and MySQL. I've gotten the latter to work - and I'm able to send queries, make tables, etc.

But I can't get PHP itself to run for some reason. I have Apache running, I have files with PHP code in them, but they don't render or throw any errors.

PHP -v returns *PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: Jun  1 2016 21:46:41)*, so it's definitely installed on the server itself. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Can you share your apache configuration? Chances are that you haven't correctly told it to route `.php` files to PHP for handling

Comment: @RobbieAverill http://pastebin.com/raw/p6VuLVV6 That's my httpd.conf

Comment: Try installing `libapache2-mod-php5`, and then restart apache server.